Cannot establish connection to sockets on a specified path in a flask application on ECS service
I have a Flask application that has a healthcheck https route /my-route and I want my socket connection to get established at /my-route/socket , when i configure the code accordingly and build docker image and run locally, the connection established on ws://localhost:3090/my-route/socket
but after deploying the image to ECS service it does not get connected on wss://dev-server/my-route/socket.
I have tried almost everything even updated the  listener rules of the ALB.
I still get a 503 error from the server. Am I missing any configurations on the server or anything?
The main thing is I can establish a connection if I do not specify any route to sockets which is is
on "wss://dev-server".
Need some help here.
Here is my app.py code snippet:
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
from chat import *
import pymongo
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = ''
socketio = SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins="*",path='/my-route/socket')
ChatSessions = {}
mongodb_uri = os.getenv("mongodb_uri")
db_env = os.getenv("db_env")
port = os.getenv('port')
client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongodb_uri)
db = client[db_env]
career_coach_data = db['career_coach']


def setup_chat(user_id):
    sid = request.sid
    user_doc = career_coach_data.find_one({'user_id': user_id})
    ChatSessions[sid] = {
                        "user_id":user_id,
                        "chat_instance":Chat(user_id=user_id),
                        "user_doc":user_doc if user_doc else None
                         }

@app.route('/my-route')
def flask_app():
    return "Mapout Career Coach Socket Application "

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/mapout-career-coach/socket')
def handle_connect():
    sid = request.sid
    user_id = request.args.get('userId')
    print(f'User ID: {user_id}')
    if user_id:
        setup_chat(user_id)
        send(" chat initiated!", namespace='/my-route/socket')
    else:
        print('userid not found!')
        # print(ChatSessions)


@socketio.on('message', namespace='/my-route/socket')
def handle_message(message):
    print(f'user message: {message}')
    sid = request.sid
    meta_data=ChatSessions[sid]
    
    if sid in ChatSessions:
        output = meta_data['chat_instance'].keep_chatting(message)
        send(output['conv_output'], namespace='/mapout-career-coach/socket')
        if output['suggestion']:
            send(output['suggestion'], namespace='/mapout-career-coach/socket')
        
        user_message = {'user': message}
        coach_reply = {'coach': output}
        
        if meta_data['user_doc']:
            career_coach_data.update_one({'user_id': meta_data['user_id']},
            {'$push': {'data': {'$each': [user_message, coach_reply]}}})
        else:
            new_user_doc = {'user_id': meta_data['user_id'], 'data': [user_message, coach_reply]}
            career_coach_data.insert_one(new_user_doc)
        
    else:
        print(f'please reconnect chat session not found for sid: {sid}')


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/my-route/socket')
def handle_disconnect():
    sid = request.sid
    if sid in ChatSessions:
        del ChatSessions[sid]
    
    print('disconnected')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=3090, debug=False)

Trying to extablish a connection to sockets at a specified route from python flask application.`
